# How to attach a description to a GeoPoint

Tags: java, android, arrays, set

I am implementing a series of markers onto a mapView in android and would like to be able to tag them with descriptions however I am having trouble finding a method of assigning descriptions to the markers.

The problem is that I need to remove the duplicate GeoPoints while still keeping the descriptions for it.

For example:

```
GeoPoint1 = [0,0] GeoPoint2 = [0,0] GeoPoint3 = [0,0]
"foo"             "bar"             "something"
```

would need to be converted into:

```
 GeoPoint = [0,0] 
 "foo, bar, something"
```

I have already used a Set to remove duplicates but as android GeoPoints only allow Lat and Long values I am unable to use this method (I think) meaning I need something different.

Any help would be great as I'm kinda stumped on it.

Thanks =D

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using the [android-mapviewballoons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons) library. It allows you to add items to an overlay with a title and description, and tapping an item shows a balloon popup with the info.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I already have something setup which allows me to add a description to the markers I need a method of removing the duplicates while keeping the tags on the same marker....if that makes sense =P